Error transfering files to Android using Windows C++ Bluetooth OBEX socket
OBEX is probably the most commonly used technique to transfer files over devices that support Bluetooth. On the contrary , with being the most common , it is not very well documented how this thing actually works.
I have not much experience in OBEX. My objective is to design an OBEX client server on my laptop which should send files to my android device with popup like this.
I have chosen C++ as the language to program the server from scratch on Windows. The UUID for this action which I am using is this.
00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

and I have initialised the OBEX client like this.
    GUID OBEX_GUID;

    UuidFromString((unsigned char*)"00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB",(UUID*)&OBEX_GUID);
    
    SOCKET soc,acpt;
    SOCKADDR_BTH BluetoothAddress;
    
    BluetoothAddress.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
    BluetoothAddress.port = BT_PORT_ANY;
    str2ba((char*)"BC:41:01:11:BC:2F",&BluetoothAddress.btAddr);
    BluetoothAddress.serviceClassId = OBEX_GUID;
     //OBEXObjectPushServiceClass_UUID;
    
    soc = socket(AF_BTH , SOCK_STREAM , BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
    
    if(soc>0){
        printf("Socket initialisation success\n");
    }
    
    stat = connect(soc,(sockaddr*)&BluetoothAddress,sizeof(BluetoothAddress));
    printf("%s\n\n",(stat==0) ? "CONNECTED to the remote device!" : "Remote device is unavailable." );
    

This connect process is successful yet , and without any error it starts communication with my Android device addressed BC:41:01:11:BC:2F. The status of the socket connect() function returns zero (success as well).
Now, as per OBEX 1.4 pdf , I need to start the session after the connection is estabilished successfully. So in the Page 38 of the PDF , the starting session of connection is  well described and I tried to imitate the syntax of the connecting package like this
char connect_req[] = {
        0x80 , 0x00 , 0x11 , 0x10 , 0x00 , 0x20 , 0x00 , 0xc0  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x01 , 0xc3       ,   0x00 , 0x00 , 0xf4 , 0x83        
    //  CNCT | 2B Length   | Vers | Flag | Max Pack 8K | Count | 4 byte file count         | Len Header |   Total length of hex
};

Upon sending this connect package to my Android, it returns successfully with the value of 0xA0. Which means that a session has finally been started.
After the session is started , I need to send a dummy file which requires to be requested as a PUT method which is defined in the page 40 of the PDF. tried to do the same imitation and ended up with a package like this.
unsigned char putfile_req[] = {
        0x82 , 0x00 , 0x21 , 0x01    , 0x00 , 0x17 ,   0x00,0x41   ,  0x00,0x42  ,  0x00,0x43  , 0x00,0x44  , 0x00,0x45 , 0x00,0x2c ,  0x00,0x74  ,  0x00,0x78 ,  0x00,0x74  ,  0xC3 ,  0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x01 ,  0x49  , 0x00 , 0x01 ,  0x74
//      PUT  |  2b Len     | HI Name |  NameLen    |       A              B             C            D             E           .           T             X            T      |  Len  |              1  Byte       |  end   |     1 Byte  |  
};
    

Upon sending this PUT request with the filename of, ABCDE.TXT (1 Byte), the response from my android somehow returns unsuccessful with the value of Zero (0)
The problem is, till the connect session state every request and response worked perfectly fine but whenever I am sending a PUT request with a file name, it is received by the Android but for some unknown reasons the Android can not proces it and returns zero.
I have heard some people saying that Android does not support OBEX but had that been the actual factor , the success (A0) status would not have returned while sending the connect package in the beginning.
Here is the full code if matters...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <ws2bth.h>
#include <bthsdpdef.h>
#include <bluetoothapis.h>
#include <ws2bth.h>

GUID OBEX_GUID;



int str2ba(const char *straddr, BTH_ADDR *btaddr)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int aaddr[6];
    BTH_ADDR tmpaddr = 0;

    if (sscanf(straddr, "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
                    &aaddr[0], &aaddr[1], &aaddr[2],
                    &aaddr[3], &aaddr[4], &aaddr[5]) != 6)
        return 1;
    *btaddr = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        tmpaddr = (BTH_ADDR) (aaddr[i] & 0xff);
        *btaddr = ((*btaddr) << 8) + tmpaddr;
    }
    return 0;
}



int main(){
    
    unsigned char response[10000]={0};
    
    UuidFromString((unsigned char*)"00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB",(UUID*)&OBEX_GUID);
    
    WSADATA ws;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&ws);
    
    int stat;
    SOCKET soc,acpt;
    SOCKADDR_BTH BluetoothAddress;
    
    BluetoothAddress.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
    BluetoothAddress.port = BT_PORT_ANY;
    str2ba((char*)"BC:41:01:11:BC:2F",&BluetoothAddress.btAddr);
    BluetoothAddress.serviceClassId = OBEX_GUID;
     OBEXObjectPushServiceClass_UUID;
    
    soc = socket(AF_BTH , SOCK_STREAM , BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
    
    if(soc>0){
        printf("Socket initialisation success\n");
    }
    
    stat = connect(soc,(sockaddr*)&BluetoothAddress,sizeof(BluetoothAddress));
    printf("%s\n\n",(stat==0) ? "CONNECTED to the remote device!" : "Remote device is unavailable." );
    
    
    
    
    char connect_req[] = {
        0x80 , 0x00 , 0x11 , 0x10 , 0x00 , 0x20 , 0x00 , 0xc0  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x01 , 0xc3       ,   0x00 , 0x00 , 0xf4 , 0x83        
    //  CNCT | 2B Length   | Vers | Flag | Max Pack 8K | Count | 4 byte file count         | Len Header |   Total length of hex
    };
    
    
    
    unsigned char putfile_req[] = {
        0x82 , 0x00 , 0x21 , 0x01    , 0x00 , 0x17 ,   0x00,0x41   ,  0x00,0x42  ,  0x00,0x43  , 0x00,0x44  , 0x00,0x45 , 0x00,0x2c ,  0x00,0x74  ,  0x00,0x78 ,  0x00,0x74  ,  0xC3 ,  0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x01 ,  0x49  , 0x00 , 0x01 ,  0x74
//      PUT  |  2b Len     | HI Name |  NameLen    |       A              B             C            D             E           .           T             X            T      |  Len  |              1  Byte       |  end   |     1 Byte  |  
    };
    
    
    printf("PUT packet Length: %d\n\n",sizeof(putfile_req)/sizeof(unsigned char));
    

    send(soc,(const char*)connect_req,sizeof(connect_req)/sizeof(connect_req[0]),0);
    int Recvd = recv(soc,(char*)response,sizeof(response),0);
    
    printf("OBEX CONNECT status: %X\n",response[0]);
    if(response[0]==0xA0){
        printf(" SUCCESS\n");
    }
    
    memset(response,0,sizeof(response));
    
    send(soc,(char*)putfile_req,sizeof(putfile_req)/sizeof(putfile_req[0]),0);
    Recvd = recv(soc,(char*)response,sizeof(response),0);
    
    printf("PUT Request status: %X\n",response[0]);
    
    if(response[0]==0x00){
        printf("Something went wrong!\n");
    }
    
    
}

And the output looks like,

Even though the connect session is successful with the return value of 0xA0, the socket closes with an error code of zero as the response of PUT request. Hence the popup dialogue at my Android side is not supposed to appear.
Now ,all I want is to send a file from the Winsock2 OBEX client written from scratch , to my Android where there should appear a popup in my Android device asking for the user to accept or decline the incoming file or request. upon acceptance , the file transfer should begin.
So this somehow seems to be my fault , which I can not diagnose. That is why I am here to ask for some kind advices and helps from those who are well experienced in this field.
Thanks and Regards.


Your name len is 23 bytes but actually it is 20. 2. You did not terminate name with /0x0000 3. You can test your android with this (includes OPP and FTP clients and OPP server): https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm


@MikePetrichenko OK changed Name len to 21 along with the addition of NULL charecter. But still no luck! I have checked my android with OBEX FTP and it pops up a dialogue to allow the laptop to access files. Upon acceptance nothing happens. Could you please spend a bit time for me recorrect and send the PUT request code? I will be very grateful for it.

Check your lengthes. Looks like body len is also incorrect, I do not remember if END-BODY is possible without BODY header. Unfortunately I implemented OBEX years ago and do not remember all the details. You connect to OPP, not to FTP. They are similar but actually different. You need to take a look Bluetooth OBEX (OPP) profile as well because it expands standard OBEX with some pre-requirements.

I have a C programmed OBEX client that sends the following commands to Android successfully. Name = hello.txt.  Data = Hello. Chunk size = 400. Data size = 5.
The data size must be sent in the 0xC3 4-byte item, your code seems to have a value of 1.
unsigned char connect[7] = {0x80,0x00,0x07,0x10,0x00,0x01,0x90};
unsigned char send[39] = {0x82,0x00,0x27,
0x01,0x00,0x17,0,'h',0,'e',0,'l',0,'l',0,'o',0,'.',0,'t',0,'x',0,'t',0,0,
0xC3,0,0,0,5,
0x49,0,8,'H','e','l','l','o'};
unsigned char disconnect[3] = {0x81,0x00,0x03};   

The sizes that must be set are as follows. Each command: bytes [1] = hi byte and [2] = lo bytes are the size of the entire packet. So send is 39 bytes = 0x0027. A put command (0x82 or 0x02) can contain a number of items, each has a header identifier 01, C3, 49 in the example. The two hi bits of the identifier specify the size of the item. 10xxxxxx is 1 byte. 11xxxxxx (C3) is 4 byte. 00xxxxx and 01xxxxxx (01, 49) are followed by two size bytes. The 01 item is 23 bytes from the initial 01 to the final 0, so is 0x0017. It is the size of the item not the file. C3 item = file size.
This is my file send routine. The write_node and read_node functions send and receive the Bluetooth packets. You will need your own implementation.
int sendfileobex(int node,char *filename)
  {
  int n,k,fn,flen,nlen,ndat,ntogo,nblock,len,err;
  unsigned char inbuf[64],send[512];
  static unsigned char connect[7] = {0x80,0x00,0x07,0x10,0x00,0x01,0x90};
  static unsigned char disconnect[3] = {0x81,0x00,0x03};   
  char *fname;
  FILE *stream;

  fn = 0;  // strip path 
  n = 0;
  while(filename[n] > 32 && n < 1022)
    {   
    if(filename[n] == '/' || filename[n] == '\\')
      fn = n+1;  // start of file name
    ++n;
    }
    
  fname = filename+fn;
  
  printf("Sending file %s\n",filename);

  stream = fopen(filename,"r");
  if(stream == NULL)
    {
    printf("File open error\n");
    return(0);
    }
  
  fseek(stream,0,SEEK_END);
  flen = ftell(stream);  // file length
  fseek(stream,0,SEEK_SET);  
    
  ntogo = flen; 
  nlen = strlen(fname);

  nblock = 400;
  connect[5] = (nblock >> 8) & 0xFF;
  connect[6] = nblock & 0xFF;

  // OBEX connect
  write_node(node,connect,7);  
  inbuf[0] = 0;
  // wait for Success reply 0x0A
  len = read_node_endchar(node,inbuf,64,PACKET_ENDCHAR,EXIT_TIMEOUT,5000);
  if(len == 0 || inbuf[0] != 0xA0)
    {
    printf("OBEX Connect failed\n");
    fclose(stream);
    return(0);
    }
  else if((inbuf[1] << 8) + inbuf[2] >= 7)
    {
    n = (inbuf[5] << 8) + inbuf[6];
    if(n < nblock)
      nblock = n;
    }
 
  send[3] = 0x01;
  n = 2*nlen + 5;
  send[4] = (n >> 8) & 0xFF;
  send[5] = n & 0xFF;
  k = 6;
  for(n = 0 ; n < nlen ; ++n)
    {
    send[k] = 0;
    send[k+1] = fname[n];
    k += 2;
    } 
  send[k] = 0;
  send[k+1] = 0;
  k += 2;

  send[k] = 0xC3;
  send[k+1] = (flen >> 24) & 0xFF;
  send[k+2] = (flen >> 16) & 0xFF;
  send[k+3] = (flen >> 8) & 0xFF;
  send[k+4] = flen & 0xFF;
  k += 5;
  err = 0;
  do
    { 
    if(ntogo <= nblock - 3 - k)
      {
      send[k] = 0x49;
      send[0] = 0x82;
      ndat = ntogo + 3;
      }
    else
      {
      send[k] = 0x48;
      send[0] = 0x02;
      ndat = nblock - k;
      } 
    send[k+1] = (ndat >> 8) & 0xFF;
    send[k+2] = ndat & 0xFF;
    k += 3;
    ndat -= 3;
    if(fread(send+k,1,ndat,stream) != ndat)
      {
      printf("File read error\n");
      err = 1;
      }
    else
      {
      ntogo -= ndat;
      k += ndat;
      send[1] = (k >> 8) & 0xFF;
      send[2] = k & 0xFF;
      write_node(node,send,k);  // send k bytes
      inbuf[0] = 0;
      len = read_node_endchar(node,inbuf,64,PACKET_ENDCHAR,EXIT_TIMEOUT,5000);
      if(len == 0 || (inbuf[0] != 0xA0 && inbuf[0] != 0x90))
        {
        printf("Send failed\n");
        err = 1;
        }
      }  
    k = 3;
    }
  while(ntogo > 0 && err == 0);  

  fclose(stream);
  
  write_node(node,disconnect,3);
  inbuf[0] = 0;
  len = read_node_endchar(node,inbuf,64,PACKET_ENDCHAR,EXIT_TIMEOUT,5000);
  if(len == 0 || inbuf[0] != 0xA0)
    printf("OBEX Disconnect failed\n");

  return(1);
  }


This worked like charm! Thank you so much my friend! however did you calculate the arrow size yourself or made use of any algorithm?

Another question, How is the size of the file named "Hello.txt" equal to 0x17 or 23?

And why is the value of second byte after End-of-Body (0x49) 8?

The sizes that must be set are as follows. Each command: bytes [1] = hi byte and [2] = lo bytes are the size of the entire packet. So send is 39 bytes = 0x0027. A put command (0x82 or 0x02) can contain a number of items, each has a header identifier 01, C3, 49 in the example. The two hi bits of the identifier specify the size of the item. 10xxxxxx is 1 byte. 11xxxxxx (C3) is 4 byte. 00xxxxx and 01xxxxxx (01, 49) are followed by two size bytes. The 01 item is 23 bytes from the initial 01 to the final 0, so is 0x0017. It is the size of the item not the file. C3 item = file size.

hey friend do you the safest byte chunk size  of a packet in bluetooth obex transfer? I am writing a file transfer application and I want to play it safe by avoiding any kind of data loss.

I've edited the answer to add my file send routine. I use a packet size of 400 because I've seen Windows fail sometimes with larger packets when transmission is slow. I guess the OBEX server will report a fail if there is data loss.

Whoops! Noticed a bug in the send code - now fixed.

After the update, your answer has become better than ever, not only for me, but also for all the future visitors.

Thanks, but found another bug now fixed. Should be flen = ftell(stream)

After @petzval's beautiful explanation, here is my understanding of how obex PUT request works
unsigned char putfile_req[] = {
        
  /*1*/      0x82 , 0x00 , 0x28 ,     /* PUT, PackSize  2 bytes*/
  
  /*2*/      0x01    , 0x00 , 0x17 ,  /* Name, Namelength 2 Bytes*/
        
  /*3*/      0x00,'A'   ,  0x00,'B'  ,  0x00,'C'  , 0x00,'D'  , 0x00,'E' , 0x00,'.' ,  0x00,'T'  ,  0x00,'X' ,  0x00,'T'  0x00,0x00,     
             /* Name of the file to be sent, in unicode with null terminator */           
        
  /*4*/      0xC3 ,  0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x05 , //Actual File Length attribute with 4 byte length describing its actual length
          
  /*5*/      0x49  , 0x00 , 0x08 ,   'B','I','T','T','U'
            /* File body or binary data.*/
   
   };
   
   
   
  1.  0x82: is the PUT and end transmission command for OBEX followed 
      by two bytes at 1st and 2nd index. The two bytes define the 
      package size as a whole in 2 byte integer. Therefore in this
      case, the size would be
        
        sizeof(putfile_req) = 40 or 0x00,0x28 (two byte definition of 40)
        
 
  2. 0x01: is the Name header that defines name attributes of the object transmitted
       It is also followed by a 2 byte integer that contais the length of
       of the whole object including the filename.
       so, the value of name header length is,
       
       strlen("ABCDE.txt") = 9
       with null terminator it becomes 9 + 1 = 10
       because file name is in unicoded, size is,
       10 * 2 = 20, with name header included it becomes
       20 + 3 = 23 (name header + 2 byte length)
       
       Formula: (strlen("ABCDE.TXT")+1)*2 + 3 = 23 
       or 0x00,0x17 (two byte definition of 23)
       
       
       
      
  3. 0x00,'A'... 0x00,0x00: The name of the file which is tobe sent.
       file name must be put as 2 byte Unicode with a 
       2 byte null terminator included as well. total 
       length of filename is 20 as described in the
       second point.
       
  4. 0xC3: This is Length header of the object being sent.
       followed by a 4 byte integer which stores the actual
       size of file. The file has 5 bytes of charecters 
       "BITTU". Hence the value will be 
       
       strlen("BITTU") = 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05 (4 byte definition of 5)


  5. 0x49: It is an End-Body header that informs the receiver 
       that the transmission is complete. Followed by an 
       integer of 2 bytes that store the binary data of the 
       file as a chunk.
       
       in this case, the value of End-Body header length is,
       
       strlen("BITTU")+3 = 0x00,0x08 (2 byte definition of 8)




After a successful OBEX connection request, this array will send a file to the android named ABCDE.TXT of 5 bytes which will have a string "BITTU" inside it. Don't forget to disconnect request the obex afterwards.

If the data will not fit in one packet, there must be put operations with an opcode of 0x02 and a data item header identifier 0x48 before the final 0x82/0x49. The server should send 0x90 CONTINUE replies to these rather than 0xA0 SUCCESS. After the first put, subsequent puts only have one item (0x48 or 0x49). The sendfileobex() code does this for large files.

Sends full file right!

Feiend, I need your help again. In the page 90 of the OBEX15 pdf, there is a demo code for Vcard which I imitated but it is not working (response code: 0xCB). Could you please add this info in your answer too?

I've never used the Vcard functions so I can't help with that.
